# BeautifulSoup extract specific items from HTML li tag

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to extract specific items from HTML li tag using BeautifulSoup. I found a bug in this part of my program which stops the program:

```
 product_url = 'https://example.com/product'
 page = sess.get(product_url)
 page = BeautifulSoup(page.text)
 list = page.select('li.items')
 list_items = [
            {
              "menu_name": menu.find('h3').text,
              "menu_type": menu.find('strong').text.strip(),
              "menu_level": menu.select('.list_item')[0].text.strip() if menu.select('.list_item') else '' ,
              "menu_url": BASE_URL + menu.select('a.title')[0]['href'],
            }
            for menu in list]
            #Any code after this line not worked
```

Also, how can I print a string inside the object for debugging?

Comment: what is the error here, and what `print list` gives

Comment: can you share the part of html file that you are extracting data from?

Comment: @YasinYousif Traceback (most recent call last):