# BeautifulSoup get element inside li tag

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having trouble parsing html element inside li tag.
This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

sess = requests.Session()

url = 'http://example.com'
page = sess.get(url)
page = BeautifulSoup(page.text)
soap = page.select('li.item')
print(soap.find('h3').text)
```

This is html code:

```
...
<li class="item">
    <strong class="item-type">design</strong>
    <h3 class="item-title">Item title</h3>
    <p class="item-description">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dicam partem praesent vix ei, ne nec quem omnium cotidieque, omnes deseruisse efficiendi sit te. Mei putant postulant id. Cibo doctus eligendi at vix. Eos nisl exerci mediocrem cu, nullam pertinax petentium sea et. Vim affert feugait an.
     </p>
</li>
...
```

There are more than 10 li tag I just paste one of them.

Output error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(soap.find('h3').text)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Comment: as mentioned below, `soap` is a list: `[s.find('h3').text for s in soap]` should help

Comment: @DaveJ thank you this worked for me

Comment: @DaveJ how can i edit this too `soap.select('.class')[0].text.strip() if soap.select('.class') else ''`

Comment: you mean like `[s.find('h3').text for s in soap if s.find('h3')]`? this might work, but it could be optimised by using a normal loop: `for s in soap: r=s.find('h3'); if r: mylist.append(s)` (we save another call to `find`).

Comment: @DaveJ I want to store them in array.  `soap_items = [
            {
              "menu_name": menu.find('h3').text,
              "menu_type": menu.find('strong').text.strip(),
              "menu_level": menu.select('.soap_item')[0].text.strip() if menu.select('.soap_item') else '' ,
              "menu_url": BASE_URL + menu.select('a.title')[0]['href'],
            }
            for menu in soap]` but it not worked

Comment: well. the given snippet does not show items like `'.soap item'` etc. `menu` will only provide the three direct children `strong`, `h3` and `p`; if you have to look a level above, `menu.parent` should be available‽

Comment: thank you so much, can you please give me the full code i tested over hundred method and searched all the day in google.@DaveJ I really appreciate if you help me

Comment: `.soap item` is also inside li I just removed it in above example. see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44843105/beautifulsoup-extract-specific-items-from-html-li-tag

Comment: As also stated in the comments of your other question: please provide more information. An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help, incl. stacktrace and/or expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @DaveJ , this method worked:

```
[s.find('h3').text for s in soap]
```